# Rails 3 Active Record Calculations: Sum and Average at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way to get activerecord to calculate the `sum` and average of a `query` at the same time ?

For example I want to do something like this - which doesn't work !

```
Person.group("gender").count.average("age")
```

And get back

```
Gender Count Average Age

Male     32    13.5

Female   26    14.7
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Person.select('gender, count(*) as count, avg(age) as avg').
       group('gender').
       order('count DESC').
       each do |p|
  puts "#{p.gender} #{p.count} #{p.avg}"
end
```

Not quite lickably pretty but still, not too fugly.